# ORA-01799 - need to correct query

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure how to rewrite the below query. I’m trying to join table_a to the most recent table_b record. Currently testing for only one ID, but a different criteria on table_a may be added:

```
Select t.*
from table_a t
left join table_b d on d.id = T.id and d.MOD_DATE IN (SELECT MAX(mod_date) FROM table_b d2 WHERE  d2.id = t.id)
where T.id = 123456
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Step 1 - determine what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DanBracuk see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT      t.*
FROM        table_a t
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      d.*
                FROM        table_b d 
                INNER JOIN  (
                                SELECT  id
                                ,       MAX(mod_date) mod_date_max
                                FROM    table_b d2 
                                GROUP BY id
                            ) db
                        ON  db.id = d.id
                        AND db.mod_date_max = d.mod_date
            ) d
        ON  d.id = T.id 
WHERE       T.id = 123456
```

Note that your `where` clause turns the `left join` into an `inner join`.

Also, if you get an error, please post the error message as well, not just its number.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same could be achieved with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a t 
WHERE id IN (
                 SELECT id 
                   FROM (
                           SELECT id,MAX(MOD_DATE) 
                             FROM table_b  
                            WHERE id = 123456
                         GROUP BY id    
                        )
            )
```